# Array: Swift and IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

All,
Can you give me a source code of my below problem?

I have 100 user array and load that array value(username) in tableview.

Scenario:

When I click any tableviewcell, i store that value in new array( userArray) and also i have displayed right side discloser (checkmark).
But my problem is when i click again to deselect that user from tablecell  my app has been crashed due to index out of bound.

I know problem is out of index, but how can i resolve that issue so if i click again on that tablecell it will remove user from userArray and i get new fresh userArray?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let tagValue = 100 + indexPath.row
let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.viewWithTag(tagValue) as UITableViewCell

if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark 
    userToSendPost.append(self.users2[indexPath.row])
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    let tempString = userToSendPost[indexPath.row] //tagvalue
    let objcArray = userToSendPost as NSArray
    let indexOfObject = objcArray.indexOfObject(tempString)
    userToSendPost.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
  }
}
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem. If not leave a comment to explain why it isn't working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this incorrectly.

On the tableview set the property `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`.

Then when you want to get the selected users...

```
let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()
```

Then you can use the `row` property from those index paths to find the users.

```
var selectedUsers: [User] = []

for indexPath in selectedIndexPaths {
    let user = theUsers[indexPath.row]

    selectedUsers.append(user)
}
```

The multiple selection and the check mark is handled automatically by the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

To follow your approach, I think this could help you ;)

But the approach of @Fogmeister is better !

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let tagValue = 100 + indexPath.row
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.viewWithTag(tagValue) as UITableViewCell

        if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            userToSendPost.append(self.users2[indexPath.row])
        } else {
            let tempUserString = self.users2[indexPath.row] // get your user string
            if contains(userToSendPost, tempString) { // check if exist on your array
                userToSendPost.removeObject(tempString) // remove it
            }
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
}


// If you want to use Array, add this method
extension Array {
        mutating func removeObject<U: Equatable>(object: U) {
            var index: Int?
            for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
                if let to = objectToCompare as? U {
                    if object == to {
                        index = idx
                    }
                }
            }

            if(index != nil) {
                self.removeAtIndex(index!)
            }
        }
}
```